# hibernate criteria returns entry twice

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have peace of code which load Categories from DB. Currently I have 3 categories. If I use native SQL or HQL inside hibernate - everything is ok. 3 categories are loaded. However when I use Criteria:

```
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return (List<Category>) session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();
}
```

I got first category two times. **Category** class is POJO class. Moreover in logs I see that *Eager load* of related entities do not work and view of resulting SQL command is different from native SQL or HQL versions.
Where can be the problem?